# How do I transform this problem into a semidefinite program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, schur-complement

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \dfrac{(c^T x)^2}{(d^Tx)}\\ \text{subject to} & Ax \leq b\\ & d^T x > 0\end{array}$$

I have been stuck on this question for a couple days. I am sharing with you what I tried, although I am pretty sure it's wrong. Please help.

---

[image]

Comment: why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the blocks in $\tilde{A}$? Do you know how to express the objective via the second-order cone?

Comment: Strict inequality?

Comment: x is n*1 , A is m*n. Does it matter what are the dimension of A_Schur?

Comment: If you have the product of $t$ and $x$ then you do not have an LMI and, thus, you do not have an SDP.

Comment: nice! thanks!
can u explain how to solve it?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming#Example_2

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=d^Tx > 0$ and $s=c^T x$. Your objective $\min t$ subject to $t \geq \frac{s^2}{r}$ is conic representable via the rotated quadratic cone (best for practical optimization):

$(t,r,s) \in \mathcal{Q}_r^3$,

or alternatively via the semidefinite cone:

$\left(\begin{array}{ll}
t & s\\
s & r
\end{array}\right) \in \mathcal{S}^2_+$

If you for some reason need a standard form SDP you need to reformulate $r=d^Tx$ and $s=c^T x$ with two inequalities each and append them to your system of inequalities $Ax \leq b$.

Comment: I would add that $t \geq 0$ because of the strict inequality constraint.

Comment: First of all thanks! I appriciate your help! Now I actually do need a standard form of SDP but i went to the duality way because i had no idea how to.. can u explain more how can u go for a standard sdp form? btw, where is the condition on Ax<=b in your solution? I will be thankful if you can write the full solution cause i feel like I don't fully understand it.. like what is the final SDP form?

Comment: @AdarCohen Linear inequality constraints can also be written in LMI form. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2817423/339790).